# I'm having trouble opening my play store

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a galaxy s3 and the play store will not open, I've  i tried every way I can think of to open it but it won't work:

I restarted my phone many times, I've also tried opening it from the application clearing page where it has the option to force close, uninstall and clear data. I also tried deleting some apps, and nothing.

When I click on it to open it opens for a second and displays Play Store on a white screen but in about a second it closes. When I'm doing anything on my phone an error saying play store has unexpectedly stopped and the only thing I can press is an "ok" button. I have also tried downloading apps directly from a website and it doesn't let me, instead it closes the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! There are a few things you could try (some you might already have tried, but it's not clear from your question): Clear cache (at the place you've described); delete data (at the same place); uninstall updates (at the same place). Try one after the other before proceding to the next; in the last two cases, a reboot might be recommended before calling up the app again. Please let us know if any of that helped.

Comment: I tried that just now and it closed after a moment, how do i reboot?

Comment: Easiest way: switch your phone off completely, and power it on again. Usually, when long-pressing the power key while the screen is on, it should give you a menu for that; on many devices this menu includes a "reboot" option.

Comment: Please don't forget to report back when your issue is solved, and how that was accomplished. Other users might profit from your experience.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>As the OP didn't report back, it seems safe to assume that the hints given in my comments to the question solved the issue:</sup>

One of the general solutions to issues with the *Google Play Store* app:

- From your homescreen, use the <kbd>menu</kbd> key/button, and go to *Settings › Apps*
- On the resulting screen, make sure to select the "All" tab
- Scroll to the *Google Play Store* entry and open it
- Chose to <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd>, then <kbd>Delete Data</kbd>, and finally <kbd>Uninstall Updates</kbd><sup>1</sup>
- Reboot your device (either by switching it off and on again, or long-press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button to bring up the "Power Menu", where you possibly can select "Reboot" directly)

---

<sup>**1:** you can try with <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> only to see if that's sufficient, and if not add the other steps one after the other until you succeed</sup>